# Why does the Fund. Theorem of Contour Integrals Need Continuity?

Tags: complex-analysis

Why does the Fundamental Theorem of Contour Integrals need continuity? When defining the integral in real analysis we don't require continuity of the function we are integrating, is it necessary to require continuity in complex analysis? This was the proof I was looking at: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Contour_Integration

Comment: When defining the integral it is over a fixed interval $[a,b]$, and continuity of $f$ is not required (but helpful). But in the realm of the FTC we are considering the integral as a function of the upper limit, which is then variable. This is a different matter.

Comment: Eric's attempt does not seem to answer your question. Note that the theorem does not say continuity is necessary, just that it is sufficient. A possible reason for assuming continuity of $f$ is that there is in this case (as far as I know) no natural analog of Riemann integrability on an interval. We are considering a function $f:D\to \mathbf C$ with $D\subseteq \mathbf C$ open so we want to require something like $f\circ\gamma$ is Riemann integrable for every curve $\gamma$ in $D$. It is not clear (to me) what simple weaker condition on $f$ than continuity will allow us to conclude this.

Answer (score 0):

The proof uses the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  A hypothesis of the [Fundamental Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Calculus) is that the integrand is continuous.  For an example of why this **really matters**, see [The Importance of Being Continuous](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/0025570x43754.di021186.02p0083t.pdf)  (Jeffrey, D.J., Mathematics Magazine, vol. 67, no. 4, Oct. 1994, pp. 294-300)

I've used a variant of equation (6) there to have students give me the (wrong) result of a definite integral of an everywhere positive integrand being zero.  A equivalent formulation of this idea appears [here](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/) (Pavlyk, Oleksandr, "Mathematica and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus", Wolfram Blog, January 19, 2008.).

Comment: The OP says himself that the fundamental theorem of calculus doesn't require continuity of the integrand and this is true.

Comment: @GitGud:  I'd like to see that statement in print.  Contra.:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part  , http://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=438  , http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremsofCalculus.html  , http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Calculus#Fundamental_Theorem_of_Calculus  , http://www-math.mit.edu/~djk/18_01/chapter13/section01.html

Comment: It's on the wikipedia's [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part): "The Second part is somewhat stronger than the Corollary because it does not assume that f is continuous".

Comment: @Wavelet:  So what is $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{4 \sin(x)+5} ~\mathrm{d}x$?  Note that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left( \frac{2}{3} \arctan\left( \frac{1}{3}\left( 4 + 5 \tan(x/2) \right) \right) \right) = \frac{1}{4 \sin(x)+5} $...

Comment: @Wavelet:  The function I give is an antiderivative of the integrand.  There are many.  Given this nonuniqueness, how would one ever believe the equations you've written?

Comment: @Wavelet: The statement you gave is true for trivial reasons: $F(a)=\int_a^a = 0$, and $F(b)$ equals the right-hand side by definition. You would need something a little bit more substantial before you could call it the "Fundamental Theorem", I think...

Comment: I feel as if I'm missing some comments, did Wavelet run away? 

Also, did we come to a conclusion on the continuity issue?

Comment: I just realized that the first theorem *does* require continuity. Whoops.

Comment: @Wavelet:  What you seem unwilling to write is that the give $F(b)-F(a) = 0$, but the integrand is everywhere positive.  This is only possible because the given antiderivative is discontinuous so the FTC does not apply.  Replace it with its continuous cousin and the result is suddenly rescued.

Comment: @GitGud:  ... and now he recants.

Comment: What @Anthony says is true, but the first theorem is not what's required for the theorem in the question. It's the second FTOC that's needed and that doesn't need continuity.

Comment: @GitGud:  I see that you need to work through the example I commented to Wavelet regarding $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{4 \sin(x)+5} ~\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: @EricTowers I don't see why I need to do that. I can 1) give you a proof that doesn't use continuity (you just asked me to show it written somewhere), 2) Ask YOU for a counterexample that without continuity the equality fails. **Edit:** And considering Blatter's [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867720/why-does-the-fund-theorem-of-contour-integrals-need-continuity/867724?noredirect=1#comment1788931_867720) and the wikipedia sentence I quoted, the burden of proof really relies on you, i.e., you should give me a counterexample.

Comment: I deleted my comments because I felt we were getting nowhere. The example you give is not a counterexample to what we were saying, 1. because the integrand is continuous, and 2. the function you propose as antiderivative is not globally an antiderivative, as it is not even everywhere differentiable. If you let $F(x)=\int_0^x \frac{1}{4\sin(t)+5}\,\mathrm dt$ you will get a proper antiderivative $F$, which will agree with your function up to a piecewise constant.

Comment: Also, the question does not ask whether the antiderivative should be continuous (an antiderivative always is, because by definition it must be differentiable), but rather its derivative. So you do not answer the question asked by the OP.

Comment: @Wavelet:  If the antiderivative is not continuous, then the equation is wrong.  The RHS is an integral, thus continuous.  The LHS therefore must be at least as continuous.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know why I am even answering anymore. An antiderivative of a function $f$ can not fail to be continuous as it is a function whose derivative (this implicitly means it is differentiable everywhere on the domain) equals $f$. $x\mapsto \frac{2}{3}\arctan\left(\frac{1}{3}(4+5\tan(x/2))\right)$ is not continuous everywhere so definitely not an antiderivative of $x\mapsto\frac{1}{4+5\sin(x)}$. If we restrict it to an interval on which it has no discontinuities then it is an antiderivative of $x\mapsto \frac{1}{4+5\sin(x)}$ on that interval.

Comment: Furthermore, I urge you to read the question again. Nowhere does the OP ask whether the antiderivative needs to be continuous (it always is). He asks whether the function itself need be continuous. He correctly recalls that for integrals on the real line we have the following theorem (Tao, Analysis I, Thm. 11.9.4): If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbf R$ is Riemann integrable and $F:[a,b]\to\mathbf R$ is an antiderivative of $f$, i.e. $F'=f$, then $$\int\limits_a^b f=F(b)-F(a)$$ The problem in the complex case (or the case for curves in $\mathbf R^n$ and functions $f:\mathbf R^n\to k$) is that we don't know

Comment: what conditions to put on $f$ that are analogous to Riemann integrability on the real line. If we consider only $C^1$ curves, we could require that $f\circ\gamma$ be Riemann integrable for every $C^1$ curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to k$, then certainly the integral $$\int\limits_\gamma f=\int\limits_a^b f\circ\gamma \cdot\gamma'$$ exists (because $\gamma'$ is continuous). However this may not be an easy to check condition, while continuity of $f$ guarantees that $f\circ\gamma$ is continuous and hence Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and hence that the integral exists.